# getting 403 forbidden error , from oauth2.0 using spring security

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security-oauth2, http-error

I've implemented oauth2.0 in using spring oauth. it's working flawlessly in localhost, but when i deploy it to server , after successfull client  credentials authorization, i'm getting 403 forbidden.

logs from localhost: works fine. returns the refresh token and access-token.

```
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3639a75a
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:211 - Request is to process authentication
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:317 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7e8cecce: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@776427a2: Username: my-trusted-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/oauth/token'; against '/oauth/token'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:218 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:347 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7e8cecce: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@776427a2: Username: my-trusted-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@34886fcd, returned: 0
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@2a0cac42, returned: 1
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:242 - Authorization successful
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:255 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:309 - /oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:861 - DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher' processing POST request for [/EWS/oauth/token]
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:306 - Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG RequestMappingHandlerMapping:316 - Did not find handler method for [/oauth/token]
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:306 - Looking up handler method for path /oauth/token
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping:313 - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException]
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'oauth2TokenEndpoint'
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter:63 - Getting access token for: my-trusted-client
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-08-15 23:16:06 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
```

logs from server after deployment to cloud: throws 403 forbidden code.

```
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/app/oauth/token'; against '/app/oauth/token'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 1 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 2 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 3 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter:128 - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1798528
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 4 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 5 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/app/oauth/token'; against '/app/oauth/token'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:211 - Request is to process authentication
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG ProviderManager:162 - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter:317 - Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7e8cecce: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@776427a2: Username: my-trusted-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 6 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 7 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:324 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 at position 8 of 8 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:151 - Checking match of request : '/app/oauth/token'; against '/app/oauth/token'
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:218 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456; Attributes: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY]
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:347 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@7e8cecce: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@776427a2: Username: my-trusted-client; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT,ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@f7e452a, returned: 0
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@24b0576d, returned: 1
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:242 - Authorization successful
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:255 - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:309 - /app/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client&username=manju&password=123456 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:116 - Chain processed normally
2016-08-14 14:45:23 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

logs don't say anything about 403 error. it skips token endpoint.

note: neither my localhost not production server has SSL.

Spring security configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- Definition of the Authentication Service -->
    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
           use-expressions="false">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
        <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <!-- Protected resources -->
    <http pattern="/rest/**"
          create-session="never"
          use-expressions="false"
          entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                       before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER"/>
        <access-denied-handler
                ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

     <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="dstest/client"/>
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler"/>

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager"/>
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/oauth/token"/> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- Authentication in config file -->
    <authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService"/>
    </authentication-manager>


     <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider  user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService">  
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />   
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Token Store  in memory
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore"/>
    -->
    <bean id="tokenStore" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
        <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="tokenServices" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore"/>
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true"/>
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails"/>
        <!-- VIV -->
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oAuth2RequestFactory" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userApprovalHandler"
          class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler">
         <property name="requestFactory" ref="oAuth2RequestFactory" />
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Token management -->
    <oauth:authorization-server client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
                                user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
        <oauth:authorization-code/>
        <oauth:implicit/>
        <oauth:refresh-token/>
        <oauth:client-credentials/>
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
                           resource-id="dstest"
                           token-services-ref="tokenServices"/>

    <!-- Client Definition -->
    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">

        <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client"
                      authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,redirect"
                      authorities="ROLE_CLIENT, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT"
                      redirect-uri="/web"
                      scope="read,write,trust"
                      access-token-validity="6000"
                      refresh-token-validity="6000"/>

    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <!--
     <sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
        <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    </sec:global-method-security>
    <oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler"/>
    <oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler"/>
    -->

    <!-- Stateless RESTful service using Basic authentication 
    <sec:http pattern="/rest/**" create-session="stateless">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern='/**' access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <sec:http-basic />
    </sec:http> -->

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <sec:http  auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" > 
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <sec:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/admin/"
            always-use-default-target="true"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>

    </sec:http>

    <!--
    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >
            <sec:password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />    
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
    -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Please post portion of the Spring security configuration code.

Comment: @11thdimension I have added spring security xml. please check.